# How to browse git branches in Trac 1.0?

Tags: git, branch, trac

I set up Trac 1.0, added the entry `tracopt.versioncontrol.git.* = enabled` to `[components]` and used the Admin panel to add my repository. While branches show up in the timeline, the source browser does not provide means to browse a different branch, tag or revision like e.g. [here](https://code.flumotion.com/trac/browser) (that site uses Trac 0.12 with the [GitPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin), which has been included into 1.0). Is there a setting I missed or does the 1.0 git integration lack this feature? The `?rev=...` parameter is simply ignored when entered manually.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your webserver?

Comment: @sudo_o Yes, and CTRL+F5'ing in firefox to be sure as well, to no avail. So you say it _should_ work with Trac 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work, but slightly different than the GitPlugin.  They allow all kinds of repositories at the top level now.  So you need to click on the top-level repo name, and then you'll see the "Visit" dropdown box appear near the top of the page.  That will allow you to select a specific branch or tag.

You can see this in Trac's own repository.  The [browser](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser) takes you too the top-level, and shows a series of repositories.  Now click on one.  For example, [`cboos.git`](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/cboos.git).  You should see the "Visit" dropdown and be able to pick a branch.

Comment: Ouch... I didn't notice that multi-repo stuff and only clicked on the small arrow next to the repo name instead of the name itself... Is there a way to open the repo by default?

Comment: Yes.  Don't give the repository a name, and it will because the default.  This works both through the admin interface and the ini file.  The information is [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ReposTracIni).  The last sentence of the first paragraph says: "The name of the default repository is empty."  I tried it on my test instance locally and it works.